# How sort list in Python 2 & 3 according to OS X ordering?

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, sorting

How can I sort a list of strings, many of which begin with oddball Unicode characters, according to the U. S. English ordering used by OS X (as in the Finder)? I need this for both Python 2.7 and Python 3.

Comment: I doubt that OS X is using a different sorting than the standard lexicographic ordering (Python's `sort`), but hey it's Apple...

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: OS X Finder (and everything else using Cocoa):
`_ ― § • = ∫ ⏘ □ ▬ ► ◾ ➜ ⟹ ⬤ ⭕ A`
  
Python, `/bin/ls` and presumably everything else not Cocoa: `⏘ = _ A § ― • ∫ □ ▬ ► ◾ ➜ ⟹ ⬤ ⭕`